ETCD backup and restore issue
I have below question on killercoda for CKA certification
Question:
For this question, please set this context (In exam, diff cluster name)
kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
etcd-controlplane pod is running in kube-system environment, take backup and store it in /opt/cluster_backup.db file.
ETCD backup is stored at the path /opt/cluster_backup.db on the controlplane node. for --data-dir use /root/default.etcd , restore it on the controlplane node itself and , and also store restore console output store it in restore.txt
ssh controlplane
Answer:
I ran below commands
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key \
  snapshot save /opt/cluster_backup.db

After running export
ETCDCTL_API=3
etcdctl --write-out=table snapshot status /opt/cluster_backup.db

I am getting as in screenshot backup output output of backup
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --data-dir=/root/default.etcd --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key \
  snapshot restore /opt/cluster_backup.db > restore.txt

But when I run cat restore.txt, I am not getting anything.

I really like how you posted an image file of text output.

ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --data-dir=/root/default.etcd --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 
--cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key 
snapshot restore /opt/cluster_backup.db > restore.txt 2>&1
--> Use 2>&1 at back to redirect the standard error and standard output to the same file.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
